# ¿Por qué no me deja agregar otra columna en una tabla de base de datos?

Tags: xampp

Me aparece este error.
#1118 - Tamaño de línea muy grande. Máximo tamaño de línea, no contando blob, es 8126. Tu tienes que cambiar algunos campos para blob.

Alguien ha tenido este error y sabe como solucionarlo?

Comment: puedes indicar la instruccion alter table que te da ese error, y el modelo de la tabla? por lo que te indica, estas superando el limite maximo de caracteres que puede tener una tabla (contando cada campo excepto el blob)...

Comment: Xampp no es una base de datos...

Comment: @Jakala es este ALTER TABLE `ratificacion` ADD `folioSinacol` VARCHAR(60) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NULL AFTER `parcialidades`;

Answer (score 0):

[image: Paso 1]

[image: Paso 2]

[image: Paso 3]

[image: Paso 4]

[image: Paso 5]

[image: Paso 6]

En el primer paso vamos a dar click primero a phpMyAdmin para que nos muestre el menú y damos click al icono de Motores.

Segundo Paso buscamos la opción de InnoDB y damos click

Tercer paso buscamos innodb_strict_mode y checamos si esta en ON, si esta en ON  hay que ejecutar la siguiente consulta.

Cuarto paso ejecutamos la query de SET GLOBAL innodb_strict_mode = 0;

Quinto paso volvemos al menú y damos click en motores y buscamos innoDB.

Sexto paso buscamos innodb_strict_mode este en OFF.

ya con estos pasos podemos resolver el error.

Comment: ¿MariaDB? ¿MySQL? XAMPP no es una base de datos, es solo una herramienta de administración.